# Issues allocating video memory

Tags: windows-10, gaming

I am trying to run Doom 3 Eternal on a HP laptop PC with Windows 10. I have allocated memory customly from System Settings, of up to 60GB. However, when I try to run Doom 3 I recevie this error message: Error, Failed to allocate video memory. Anybody knows why?
Thanks!

System Specs:
Processor: AMD A4-9120 RADEON R3, 4 compute cores 2c + 2g 2.20Ghz,
Graphics: AMD R3 integrated,
RAM: 4GB,
System: 64 bit operating system, x64 based processor

Comment: What specifications are your PC? What graphics card does it have? Doom3 is a demanding game so Intel graphics is not going to be enough.

Comment: What *exactly* did you do to "allocated memory customly from System Settings, of up to 60GB" because that doesn't sound like it does what you think it does.

Comment: It is AMD Radeon with AMD R3 graphics.
And I have allocated custom memory from System--> Performance--> Advanced --> custom memory (I have googled it and they say that increasing memory size will allow it to run.) I know that DOOM 3 is a demanding game. I have also updated the drivers through the AMD website, using AMD Adrenaline, so the driver is up to date.. still, nothing.

Comment: Don’t forget to revert the virtual memory settings to “Automatic”. Otherwise you may be wasting lots of storage space.

Comment: I have, thank you Daniel :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hardware is insufficient to support Doom.

> Graphics: AMD R3 integrated, RAM: 4GB

This means that your graphics processor is your CPU, rather than a dedicated Graphical Processing Unit/GPU. When you use an integrated GPU, you are using system RAM as memory for the integrated GPU. This means that not only is the memory for your graphics slower than dedicated GDDR, but its capacity is shared with the system (or rather the systems capacity is shared with it).

The error you are seeing states: "Error, Failed to allocate video memory" because you have 4Gb of system RAM, which i'm assuming more than half is allocated to the operating system (and probably using SWAP heavily too), and then you are asking the game to load its program, libraries, as well as graphical memory all into that tiny 4Gb.

I understand that you have increased your virtual memory / SWAP, however this is not a solution. The swap is used to cache inactive memory in most situations. If your system is actively using swap as a memory storage medium then not only is everything going to become slugishly slow, but you would be lucky to see a single frame per second (unplayable).

When you combine all of this together, I'm afraid to say that you are nothing short of looking for an entirely new laptop/system in order to be able to play Doom3.

Your CPU, RAM, GPU are insufficient to even load the game, let alone play it.

My condolences.

Comment: Okay, I thought so but it was worth giving a try.. however, I am looking into purchasing a Desktop system... that should sort the problem. Thank you for the condoleances, they are accepted :D